# hostgator Add-on domain problems

Tags: hosting, subdomain, google-search

i have many Add-on domain in my account ...but facing problem in search now ... my Add-on domain are shown as sub domain in search.... i have a hosting with other companies also but never face this problem before ... if u search "grdps.com punjab" it will give **grdps.ukwebsitedesigners.net**
instead of
**grdps.com** ... why?
 all my sites are having this issue ans i am getting affected if google search ...
 please help ....is there a way to solve it and where is the issue ?? hosting ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the ans i have added Disallow: in robots.txt and redirect my sub domain to main domain ... and problem solved